# Issues with Gatsby & Strapi optional data

Tags: graphql, gatsby, strapi

I have a model made in Strapi which contains a specific component which can be used to add social media links. Each link contains a text field and a link field. Everything works as expected, except when I leave it empty. If there are 0 links I get an error which is shown below.

This is how the component looks inside Strapi:
[image]

Gatsby GraphQL trying to access the links:

```
strapiWebsiteSetting {
    footerSocialLinks {
      text
      link
    }
    footerOtherLinks {
      text
      link
    }
  }
```

The error I get when there is 0 links added:
[image]

Is there a way of making GraphQL work even if there is 0 links added. I've tried
adding the following code to `gatsby-node.js` but that didn't work:

```js
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
    const { createTypes } = actions;
    const typeDefs = `
      type STRAPI__COMPONENT_LINK_FOOTER_OTHER_LINK implements Node {
        id: ID!
        parent: Node
        children: [Node!]!
        internal: Internal!
        text: String
        link: String
        strapi_id: Int
      }
      type STRAPI__COMPONENT_LINK_FOOTER_SOCIAL_MEDIA_LINK implements Node {
        id: ID!
        parent: Node
        children: [Node!]!
        internal: Internal!
        text: String
        link: String
        strapi_id: Int
      }
    `;
    createTypes(typeDefs);
};
```

Answer (score 5):

A less painful way to make gatsby and strapi work with optional attributes and even optional records is the following:

1. Install the `gatsby-plugin-schema-snapshot` plugin.
2. Set the "update" option to "true" in gatsby-config.js (could also be handled by environment variable):

```js
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-schema-snapshot`,
      options: {
        update: true,
      },
    }
```

3. Build your app with all content-types having at least one record (e.g. a dummy record) and all attributes present. That creates a schema.gql file in the root of your app folder.
4. Set the plugin's "update" option to "false" and remove your dummy record.
5. Build again. No complaints anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I managed to get it working. Creating the custom types in the `gatsby-node.js` probably did the trick, but I haven't really tested it, I just know it works.

Comment: can you share your solution

Comment: @Yasir I'm sorry I would, but I moved away from using Gatsby, so I don't have the solution anymore.